# Why do many versions of Ehcache in the Maven repo not have jars?

Tags: maven, ehcache

If you look into the Maven repo for [Ehcache](http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/net/sf/ehcache/ehcache/) for many version between [1.7.0 (first not to)](http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/net/sf/ehcache/ehcache/1.7.0/) and [2.7.0 (first to contain again)](http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/net/sf/ehcache/ehcache/2.7.0/) they contain no jars.

I am asking because I am trying to build an older project that depends on 1.7.2 and I'm getting the error:

```
Downloading: http://mvnrepo.initech.net/archiva/repository/snapshots/net/sf/ehcache/ehcache/1.7.2/ehcache-1.7.2.jar
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/net/sf/ehcache/ehcache/1.7.2/ehcache-1.7.2.jar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 11.871s
[INFO] Finished at: Wed Jul 24 15:17:44 EDT 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 6M/152M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project initech-fintools-business: Could not resolve dependencies for project net.initech:initech-fintools-business:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact net.sf.ehcache:ehcache:jar:1.7.2 in initech_center (http://mvnrepo.initech.net/archiva/repository/Initech_Center) -> [Help 1]
```

I should mention that I am using Maven 3.1.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may already know, but when searching for Maven artifact, you can use http://search.maven.org

The reason why you couldn't find any JARs is because ehcache was split into several artifacts for these versions.

You can check http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C2%7Cg%3A%22net.sf.ehcache%22%20AND%20a%3A%22ehcache-core%22

I think the JAR you are searching for is [here : ehcache-core-1.7.2.jar](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Cnet.sf.ehcache%7Cehcache-core%7C1.7.2%7Cjar)

So you must replace in your POM

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
  <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
  <version>1.7.2</version>
</dependency>
```

with

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
  <artifactId>ehcache-core</artifactId>
  <version>1.7.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Split was probably done as project was growing with more and more stuff. They may have re-added a big one JAR in the latest versions for convenience.

**EDIT :**

If you need both `ehcache-core` and `ehcache-terracota`, you can simply use :

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
  <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
  <version>1.7.2</version>
  <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

Comment: That makes sense, but then why does it have the "empty" projects at all in the repo?

Comment: These projects are not empty : the pom itself is the artifact (i.e. it has the packaging POM, see http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/net/sf/ehcache/ehcache/1.7.0/ehcache-1.7.0.pom). The POM is here to be used as a facility to get both `ehcache-core` and `ehcache-terracota` with only one dependency. I've edited my answer to show the usage.

Comment: Thank you! I had never seen that before.